# how to get inversion count with update

Tags: count, mergesort, inversion, binary-indexed-tree

Inversion count in an given array is a very famous with a time complexity of O(NlogN). However, I wonder whether there is a way to do it with update.
Input format:
first line consist of an integer n;
second line includes n integer which is the array
the next line includes m the number of update
the following m lines has intergers, x and y. You have to update the number at index x to y and output the number of inversion.
Output:
the output consist of m lines. one integer for each update/query

Can any help me to solve (#no offline programming)?